# DynamoDB UpdateItem to use ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure with UpdateItemSpec

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have some existing code that calls DynamoDB using this "medium-level" Java client, and the arguments are provided through this spec class: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/UpdateItemSpec.html. You can find many examples of how this is used [here](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-api/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/updateitemspec/updateitemspec-0-1.html). For example:

```java
@Override
public void announce(long stateVersion) {
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

    UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("namespace", blobNamespace)
            .withUpdateExpression("set #version = :ver").withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#version", "version"))
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber(":ver", stateVersion));

    table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
}
```

Recently DynamoDB added a feature that allows UpdateItem to return the old item data in the case of conditional check failures, by providing this arg in UpdateItem request: `ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure`, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html.

How should I use this in `UpdateItemSpec`?

I did not find documentation for this so there is nothing I can try. My goal is to be able to use `ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure` for debugging purpose when conditional failures happen. I'd like to know if it is possible to achieve this without switching to the low-level client that uses `UpdateItemRequest` instead of `UpdateItemSpec`. Also, if possible, does DynamoDB plan to update this `UpdateItemSpec` to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with this specific client today, as it's a new release and only released to the low level clients initially.

While I can't speak directly for the SDK team, I would be skeptical that it would be added to this library as it is based on SDK V1 while it's suggested that users should migrate to SDK V2 libraries where features will be more likely to be implemented.